# HTML5 <figure> usage in my case

Tags: html, figure

What should I do in this case:

```
        <figure>
            <a href="#" class="portfolio-item">
                <div class="picture"><img src="images/portfolio/recent-01.jpg" alt=""/><div class="image-overlay-link"></div></div>
                <figcaption class="item-description">
                    <h5>Mountain Landscapes</h5>
                    <span>Photography</span>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>
```

I can't use "figcaption" outside "a" element, but I want to make hover both on text area and image. Maybe "article" would be better?

Comment: What's the problem with what you have here?  <a> can contain block elements in html5.

Comment: W3C validator says that I can't use "figcaption" inside "a".

Comment: Why not put the `a` element around the `figure` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your CSS looks, you could contain each of the image and the caption in separate anchor tags, like the following:

```
<figure>
    <div class="picture">
        <a href="#" class="portfolio-item">
            <img src="images/portfolio/recent-01.jpg" alt=""/>
            <div class="image-overlay-link"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <figcaption class="item-description">
        <a href="#" class="portfolio-item">
            <h5>Mountain Landscapes</h5><span>Photography</span>
        </a>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Or you could put the picture div container class in the anchor or image tag, that way you wouldn't need the encompassing div.

If you only wanted some hover effect to take place, you could also just use CSS, and target the .picture:hover selector and keep the anchor tag on the figcaption. Depending on what you need.

And to answer your `article` suggestion, that's for what the [W3C calls syndicated content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-article-element). You might try [`section`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-section-element), instead, which offers an element that designates a piece of a document you would include in an outline or that are thematically similar––if you are to go that route.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using `a` outside figure, as [suggested by Alohchi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829796/html5-figure-usage-in-my-case#comment19041433_13829796)? This is valid:

```
<a href="#" class="portfolio-item">
    <figure>
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="images/portfolio/recent-01.jpg" alt=""/>
            <div class="image-overlay-link"></div>
        </div>
        <figcaption class="item-description">
            <h5>Mountain Landscapes</h5>
            <span>Photography</span>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</a>
```

Comment: I agree with this, though it is probably worth mentioning...because a figure can contain multiple elements or images, such as social media icons, that this may not be the most effective. That being said, you can only have ONE figcaption and should probably in the beginning or the end of the figure element. Again, right answer but I wanted to add this insight.

Comment: I agree with your explanation but don't agree with your example. Social media icons shouldn't be on this kind of markup, there are other better options to that nowadays.